# How to read all the bytes from Serialport as indicated by BytesToRead

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to read data off a meter. The holy grail is `1000 samples per second` which the device actually supports. Baud rate is `38400, Parity.None` and `Stopbits.One` if that matters. I am using the `binary mode` to keep things as swift as possible. I plan using the DataReceived event as below.

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int bytesToRead = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[bytesToRead];
        int actualBytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            actualBytesRead = serialPort.Read(data, 0, bytesToRead);
        } while (actualBytesRead != bytesToRead);

        //At this point assume that the data byte array has all the data
    }
```

**It seems that `BytesToRead` will return all the bytes which are available to read for that event.** However as the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx) says

```
The SerialPort class buffers data, but the stream object contained in the
SerialPort.BaseStream property does not. Therefore, the SerialPort object
and the stream object might differ on the number of bytes that are 
available to read. When bytes are buffered to the SerialPort object, the 
BytesToRead property includes these bytes in its value; 
however, these bytes might not be accessible to the stream contained in
the BaseStream property.
```

**And `Read` returns only the number of bytes it has read.**
So as a precaution against this I plan to read continually till I get the number of bytes read same as what BytesToRead indicated for the event raised. However there are few points I am not clear on.

- Will this even work. I am not sure if the data once read off the buffer of a serial port will remain to exist.
- If not then while looping around should I keep the number of bytes to read equal to BytesToRead or should I adjust it for the number of bytes already read from the buffer.
- I am pretty much hitting the buffer constantly till I get all the bytes. Is this right? Will this lead to locking issues in the sense that bytes will take longer to become available?
- Is there any better way to get all the bytes as indicated by BytesToRead?

Comment: The note is clumsy, do note that you linked to the wrong MSDN article.  The Read() article does not have this note.  The difference is related to the *Encoding* property, it starts to matter when you read strings instead of bytes.  Like you do when you use ReadExisting().  BytesToRead always tells you about the number of *bytes* you can expect to read, it does not tell you anything about the number of *characters* you can read.  So no, that do-while loop does not make sense, it never loops.

Comment: @HansPassant: Fixed the link. The serial port [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx) does mention this: "Because the SerialPort class buffers data, and the stream contained in the BaseStream property does not, the two might conflict about how many bytes are available to read. **The BytesToRead property can indicate that there are bytes to read, but these bytes might not be accessible to the stream contained in the BaseStream property because they have been buffered to the SerialPort class.** ". When all the bytes indicated by BytesToRead are available?

Answer (score 3):

The following is wrong:

```
int actualBytesRead = 0;
do
{
    actualBytesRead = serialPort.Read(data, 0, bytesToRead);
} while (actualBytesRead != bytesToRead);
```

In each iteration of the loop you are always passing 0 for `offset`, so each time you read bytes you are overwriting bytes that were previously read.

I would rewrite it as follows:

```
for( int offset = 0;  offset < data.Length;  )
{
    int n = serialPort.Read( data, offset, data.Length - offset );
    offset += n;
}
```

Comment: So that means that once I manage to read of n 'available' bytes then they disappear from the port buffer. I was under impression that they linger around till the next event, no matter how many time I read them. Hence thought of brute forcing my way through reading the whole thing and overwriting what I have from previous reads.

Comment: Yes, that's how `Read()` functions usually work.  But Hans Passant is probably right, if your `data` is exactly `serialPort.BytesToRead` bytes long, the loop will most probably execute exactly once, it will not repeat.

Comment: This statement:
var bytesToRead = serialPort.BytesToRead is acting funny. 
Debugger shows bytesToRead=136 and serialPort.BytesToRead=1867. It is almost as if after assignment BytesToRead value changed. I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: @NotAgain yes, I suspected that much.  The documentation hints that something like this may happen, but it is very unclear about it.  I would expect the event to be re-issued, and I presume that the problem that you are having is that it is not re-issued.  However, I don't think that this should be a big problem.  All it means is that you need to keep executing the code inside your `serialPort_DataReceived()` until `_serialPort.BytesToRead` returns zero.  This means that you will be left with many `data` arrays, and you will need to figure out what to do with them.